# JavaFX BorderPane set multiple buttons to Bottom?

Tags: java, javafx, layout, borderpane

Is it possible to have multiple `Buttons` set to `Bottom` (left, center, right)?

This is what I tried:

```
    private Pane createPane() {
        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
        rootPane.setTop(createMenueBar());
        rootPane.setCenter(createTableView(model.getIssues()));
        
        rootPane.setBottom(createDeleteIssueButton());  
        rootPane.setBottom(createCloseIssueButton());
        rootPane.setBottom(createCreateNewIssueButton());
        
        BorderPane.setAlignment(deleteIssueButton, Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(closeIssueButton, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(createIssueButton, Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        return rootPane;
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see it only shows the last added `Button`. What is the best way to get this done with JavaFX/BorderPane? I'm very new to this so let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Nested layouts

Gather the multiple buttons into a [layout manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_manager). Place that layout manager object in the bottom position of your `BorderPane`.

For example, you might choose `FlowPane` as your layout manager.

```
FlowPane buttons = new FlowPane() ;
buttons.getChildren().addAll( deleteIssueButton , closeIssueButton , createIssueButton ) ;
```

The `BorderPane` places only a single widget in the bottom slot. You want your container of buttons to be that widget.

```
BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();
rootPane.setBottom( buttons ) ;
```

Your use of `Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT` and such determines where the widget is placed within the bottom slot. The `BOTTOM` in `BOTTOM_LEFT` means bottom slot of the given space within a slot, not the bottom of the `BorderPane`. Two different bottoms involved here.

```
BorderPane.setAlignment( buttons , Pos.CENTER ) ;
```

Comment: how would I do that ? Never used a layout manager before

Comment: @Chris Yes, you did use a layout manager before. The `BorderPane` is a layout manager.

Comment: so I create another `Pane` , then add the buttons to `left`, `center` & `right` and then add the `Pane` to the bottom to `rootPane`?

Comment: @Chris Yes. You can nest various layout managers within other layout managers. If you think creatively, you can create nice forms this way. But don't go crazy, minimize your nested layouts where you can. But do nest them where needed to get an effective layout.

Comment: that worked thanks! one more thing, what would I have to do if I wanted to have the first two button allign left, next to each other,  and the last button on the right ?

Comment: @Chris And the fun begins… You need to practice with all the various layout managers, to get familiar. Then you will be able arrange your widgets in more sophisticated layouts as you ask.

Comment: @Chris Read some tutorials on JavaFX/OpenJFX layout managers. I have seen some good ones. Visual screenshots will bring home the concepts for you. And you may find similar tutorials for [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) — you can skim through these too to glean ideas as some of the layout managers are quite similar in concept ( `BorderPane` in JavaFX is a copy of `BorderLayout` in Swing), but ignore the Swing code details.